# Communicate better practice to a business owner

Tags: management, productivity

I have once worked for this business owner, which I've gotten pretty friendly with. The reason I quit is because his management style.

The problem: there is no ticketing system for the IT department. I once implement a very simple one - using paper on my computer or email, so I can track what problem I currently have, and what have I've done to fix it. Colleagues simply refuse to do so, and my complaint fall to the deaf ears.

After my resignation, it seems he has been more open to ideas and advices, and I would like to approach him to share better practices on establishing a solid IT department.

**How could I propose these ideas without offending him?**

Why I'm interested: I've been on friendly terms with the whole company, and I would like to see it mature. I'm interested in going back somewhere in the future after this company has become more organized.

Edit: I'm intending to invite him for a lunch together, and casually suggest ideas on him. However, I'm afraid of being seen as "teachy" as obviously I'm far younger than him by at least 30 years.

Comment: I don't get the issue here. He has openly asked you for ideas but you think he might get offended if you actually give him ideas? Please edit the question to provide more context.

Comment: No, he's not asking me, rather I want to share better practices (especially implemented on IT department). I still met him occasionally when I visit his cafe. I don't want he get offended if I offered him advice out of nowhere (unasked)

Comment: So how do you know he is open for ideas if he hasn't asked you? I would advise you to stay out of it. You have left the job, what they do there now is not your problem, don't go looking for trouble.

Comment: I'm still in contact with my ex colleagues, and they mentioned he is far more reasonable than before. I've personally met him and talked a bit about the company when I visit his cafe, and it all went good.

Comment: Sounds totally bizarre.  Get on with your life.  If, as it happens, you want to work there again ( why ??? ) walk up up them and say "you want to work there again".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, best practice is don't get involved with anything work related at a former workplace unless they're paying you to do so. Social contact is fine, but best to never go in depth on anything about your former workplace, people or work.

There is no reliable gain for you and you never know someones agenda and what possible harm it can do.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldnt get involved due to other answers

But if you are like me you want the how to get involved lol. What you can do is, on a friendly conversation, talk about your previous experience as if it had nothing to do with them. And if you can talk of how google, or third party company, used something similar which saved them x in y that usually hits the spot as they reflect on the story and don't even take it as if you were suggesting it.

Just talk about the nightmare before, dont mention anything related to them.